# How make std::set insertions faster?

Tags: c++, stl, set

I am using the `std::set` container to store some scalar integer values. I've noticed that the `insert` operation is slow when I call it in a loop. How can I make it faster?

Here is some representative code:

```cpp
std::set<unsigned long> k;
unsigned long s = pow(2,31);
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < s; i++){
    k.insert(i);
}

std::cout << k.size() << std::endl;
```

This code takes a very long time to execute. How can I modify this code (and/or change my algorithm) in order to make it run faster?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243654/discussion-on-question-by-turtle-97-how-make-set-function-faster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How make set function faster?

You can make this faster by using hints, since you know that every insert is to the end of the set:

```
for(unsigned long i = 0; i < s; i++){
    k.insert(k.end(), i);
}
```

Alternatively, you could potentially make it faster using another data structure, such as `std::unordered_set` for example.

Most significantly, you could make it faster by not creating such a massive set in the first place. For example, if you need to know whether some `unsigned long ul` is in the set of integers [0, s), then you can simply use `ul < s` instead of creating the set that contains all the integers.